# Are there any benefits from using booleans to index a list of functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

### Research

Lately, I've been playing around with different ways to write the same python code. One of the most exciting things I found was the discussion surrounding the use of a `dict` of functions to replace the use of `if ... else` (as shown in some of the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60208/14642821) question) and it seems that the overall understanding is that it is better performance-wise, but it might reduce the **code's readability**.

### Code

Similarly, I tried using a `dict` of boolean keys and function values with a `.get(...)()` at the end. The only problem is that it is limited to only two functions.

Then, I came up with this solution (it sounds confusing but I don't know how else to put it):

- using a `list` of functions indexed with the value returned from the `.index(True)` method of a `list` of conditions (booleans).

Here is the overall syntax:

- `[f_a, f_b, ..., f_n, default][[condition_a, condition_b, ..., condition_n, True].index(True)](*args)`

And an example:

```
def foo(x):
    print("x is greater then 10")

def bar(x):
    print("x is negative")

def baz(x):
    print("x is 5")
   

x = int(input("x: ").strip())

[foo, bar, baz, lambda x: None][[x > 10, x < 0, x == 5, True].index(True)](x)
```

### Question

All in all, I know that this is not pythonic at all, it has terrible readability and it would be a nightmare to debug and maintain, but I was wondering ***how would this impact the performance of my code***. I also wanted to know ***if it was all*** `lambda` ***functions inside the list would it be better or worse?***